# How to use Remmina or any alternative to connect to windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, rdp, remmina, tsclient

I'm new here & I just tried to connect to windows 7 on my laptop from Ubuntu 12.04 on my pc. First i tried tsclient but i couldn't isntall it on Ubuntu 12.04. Then I tried Remmina.
The problem now is I can't use it, I dunno how I should configure it. I tried some ways by myself but they didn't work.

Is there any guidance about using Remmina or anything else which helps me plz?

Answer (score 1):

**To Enable Remote Desktop (RDP) on Win 7:-**
Right Click My Computer > Properties
Click Remote Settings
In the Lower "remote Desktop" Pane Click
"allow connections form computers running any version of Remote Desktop"

Answer (score 0):

First you should setup Windows to enable remote desktop connection (choose a user, password) then finally open Remmina, choose RDP protocol, type username/password (configured in Windows RDP), ip address of your laptop with windows and voila!

Answer (score 0):

When you start remmina you get this window
[image]

(but without any entries), click on the green "plus" to get the following window

[image]

Here you must enter the remote machine's IP-address (or name), your username/password on the remote machine (if you leave the password out you are prompted for it during the actual connection) and the domain/workgroup to use.

The other tabs can stay as they are (for the moment at least). Now first click *save*, then *connect*, the remote machine will "appear".

Answer (score 0):

You will also want to change the default settings in Remmina for:-
Colour Depth. Set 24 or 32 bit. the default 8 bit is unusable
Resolution.
Depending on the target and your own Screen sizes some experimentation may be required.

The Remmina Scale Mode works very well, and allows you to fit ALL the target screen into your Remmina RDP Window.
I found creating some Custom resolutions was very handy, to create a window which fits nicely on my screen without scrollbars, and then use Scale mode to fit the target into that.
EG on my 1366 x 768 screen,  I use a custom resolution of 1024 x 640, which gives me a window that fits my screen leaving the Unity Top & Side menus visible, along with a bit of space to reveal windows of other apps.

The Group Function is handy if you have many target systems. In my case I create one for each of my customers, and then group machines by customer.